# Android Studio 2.1 does not show local variables when debugging

Tags: debugging, android-studio, android-studio-2.0, android-studio-2.1

My AS stopped showing local variables. Currently I'm using AS 2.1, but tried AS 2.0 and AS 1.5.1. It started some time ago, I guess with the update to 2.0. I've moved to the older version but it did not help. I'm using build tools 23.0.3, and gradle 2.1.0. I've also added

```
testCoverageEnabled false
```

to build.gradle.

There are very little info about that issue around the internet, one I've found: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=123771

If anybody had that issue, please share some info.

Comment: I hope you are working with the latest Android Studio now.

Comment: @PratikButani why? it still has the same problems. You can't read variable data even tho it literally just assigned it